# Can't delete, chown or chmod file even as root

Tags: chmod, rm, chown, named-pipe, fifo

I want to delete a backup of a website (FTP-mirrored with `wget`), but a single file, named `js_composer.less` resists. I can create new files and delete them in the same directory, so the problem might be with the file itself.

It can't be **force-deleted**:

```
$sudo rm -f js_composer.less
rm: cannot remove 'js_composer.less': Operation not permitted
```

I can't change its **permissions**:

```
$sudo chmod 644 js_composer.less
chmod: changing permissions of 'js_composer.less': Operation not permitted
```

I can't change its **owner**:

```
$sudo chown myuser:mygroup js_composer.less
chown: changing ownership of 'js_composer.less': Operation not permitted
```

I can't list the **file's attributes**:

```
$sudo lsattr js_composer.less 
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on js_composer.less
```

From `ls` I can see that it's a named pipe (FIFO) with **sticky bit** (restricted deletion flag) applied:

```
p-ws-wS--t 41284 30917 5212 3944510081 márc  14  1902 js_composer.less
```

Now I don't see any way to get rid of this file. What else could I try?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u marc rm  js_composer.less` ?

Comment: Thanks @EugenRieck, I tried `sudo -u \#30917 rm js_composer.less` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's an item with nonsense permissions and 41284 hardlinks. It's a named pipe with alleged size of 3.7 GiB, which is 3.7 GiB larger than a named pipe should be (and it wasn't supposed to *be* a named pipe in the first place).

It's a sign that you shouldn't be trying to delete it – instead you should be running `fsck` against the partition and letting it fix any filesystem corruption that it can find. *Then* you might be able to simply delete the bad file.

If this happened on your root filesystem, reboot with the kernel option `fsck.mode=force`. If the filesystem is separate (e.g. you have a separate /home partition), you can alternatively reboot into recovery mode and run `fsck <device>` manually.

After the check finishes, try rebooting into normal mode and removing the file again.

---

Finally, if nothing else helps, most filesystems have "debugfs"-type tools which can directly edit and remove inodes and directory entries, bypassing the kernel's filesystem code. For example, ext4 has `debugfs` and XFS has `xfs_db`. Using them would be a separate thread on its own...

Comment: Thank You, that's probably the case. There has been some partition warnings and repairs going on at system startup lately. The file is on my separate home partition, I just need to figure out, how to enter recovery mode in my Libreboot (: I'll get back to You when I've tried it.

Comment: I made a live USB, booted in it, mounted the encrypted disk, then ran `sudo fsck /dev/mapper/master-home`. It outputted "clean", which I guess means it didn't find any errors, but it was very quick, almost instantaneous, which I find suspicious. Should I go aloing with `debugfs` tools?

Comment: Run it with the `-f` option to perform a full check.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had to specify the FS type, so it was `sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/mapper/master-home`, but it worked (I've never did a FS check manually before). And of course, all the errors were related to that single inode. After accepting all the repairs, the file was gone.